# Can't fine element text with XPath

Tags: python, selenium, element

There is a question bothering me for a long time.
I'm studying in web element locating and control/read text from a web page.

I've to try to commend blow and fine element success but return empty.

```
driver.find_element(By.XPATH, '//table[1]//tr[2]//td[1]').text
```

I want to read text the blue line text in the PIC, but I don't know why to get empty data every time.

[image]

Comment: Share the HTML code in text format. How did you know that it's returning a null , did you print it ?

Comment: Do you mean that you get *empty output* or you get an Exception?

Comment: >>> driver.find_element(By.XPATH, '//table[1]//tr[2]//td[1]').text

''

>>>\n
this his my commend return

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That's because table located inside an iframe. To be able to handle table you have to switch to that frame:

```
driver.switch_to.frame('frame')
```

If you can locate element, but code returns you empty string, you can try

```
# In case element is hidden
driver.find_element(By.XPATH, '//table[1]//tr[2]//td[1]').get_attribute('textContent')

# In case text generated dynamically:
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait as wait

wait(driver, 5).until(lambda driver: driver.find_element(By.XPATH, '//table[1]//tr[2]//td[1]').text)
```

Comment: Thanks, I've switch to the frame , it will return error if not. i'll try your suggest and get feedback to you.

Comment: Sorry !! My bad, I get text already, it's because I forget to print return value.
Thanks a lot ,all of you.

Answer (score 0):

```
driver.switchTo().frame("your frame")
Relative xpath:-driver.findelementByxpath("//td[@id='o_B1_2']");
absolute xpath:-driver.findElement(By.xpath("//table//tr[3]//th//td[1]"));;
```

Comment: as much as i can see there is 3 tr under table and your td is in 3rd tr.Although as i much as i would suggest get it by relative xpath in that way even if new element is added or deleted from table your xpath will work just fine.